# Play a sound once using Java Audio Synthesis System (JASS)

Tags: java

Does anyone know how to play a sound file just one time using JASS? I can play sound using `SourcePlayer` but this is a thread and it plays over and over again.

I am using the code below:

```
SourcePlayer player;
LoopBuffer loopbuffer;
Mixer mixer;
String wavfile = "sounds/ur.wav";

public void start(int speed) {
    float srate = 44100.f;
    int bufferSize = 128*4;
    int bufferSizeJavaSound = 8*1024;

    loopbuffer = new LoopBuffer(srate, bufferSize, wavfile);

    mixer = new Mixer(bufferSize, 1);
    mixer.setGain(0,1);

    player = new SourcePlayer(bufferSize, bufferSizeJavaSound, srate);
    try {
        player.addSource(mixer);
        mixer.addSource(loopbuffer);           
    } catch(SinkIsFullException e) { }

    float val = (float)(.95 + speed/20.);

    loopbuffer.setSpeed((float)val);

    player.start();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used JAAS but you can comfortably play *.wav file using the javax.sound package,the snippet is as below:

```
File soundFile = new File("path_to_file\\doorbell.wav");
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
clip.open(inputStream);
clip.stop();//to avoid overlaps
clip.setFramePosition(0);
clip.start();
```

hope this helps...happy Coding

Comment: Fast and clean solution. But can I change frequency of the sound using   `javax.sound`?

Comment: i have never tried it but this might get you some insight: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2226701/Java-Sound-Creating-Playing-and-Saving-Synthetic-Sounds.htm